# How to take values from columns and add to a single row in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set as shown below

```
Product_ID    Type      Description
12              A       Made of wood
12              B       Made of wood
25              C       Made of steel
```

I need to get a dataset like the below, basically the values from Type column is added to the description within paranthesis, any thoughts? Please note that the description is the same for Type A and B.

```
Product_ID   Description
12           Made of wood ( A,B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new variable and retain the value.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by product ;
  length new_description $200 ;
  if first.product then do;
     if last.product then new_description=description;
     else new_description=trim(description)||'('||type;
  end;
  else do;
     new_description=catx(',',new_description,type);
     if last.product then new_description=cats(new_description,')');
   end;
   if last.product;
    retain new_description;
    keep product new_description;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation of concatenations exercise that can be solved using the DOW loop technique.  You might want a data validation step beforehand to ensure each product_id has only one description.

```
data want;
  do until(last.product_id);
    set have;
    by product_id description;
    length types $100;
    types = catx(',', types, type);
  end;
  description = trim(description) || ' (' || trim(types) || ')' ;
run;
```